# Custom component (Vanilla JavaScript) scroll event on window object in shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, window, addeventlistener, shadow-dom, custom-component

I am currently rewriting my `<header></header>` inside an `index.html` file with JavaScript functions. Every function was working perfectly fine.

The struggle comes with rewriting it as a custom component so I do not have to repeat the header code in every page (there are many). But the functionality is not that easy to rewrite because it seems I do not have access to certain things.

The custom header-component, everything working as expected:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    .content-container {
    color: inherit;
    margin-inline: auto;
    max-width: 73.75rem;
    width: 90vw;
    }

    .header {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    }

    a {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul {
      background-color: inherit;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    .header-container {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      gap: 1.5rem;
      padding: 1rem 0;
    }

    .logo {
      flex-shrink: 1;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 3.375rem;
      max-width: 15.5rem;
      padding-left: unset;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-top {
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: end;
    }

    .nav-top a:hover,
    .active {
      color: var(--clr-primary);
      border-block-end: 2px solid var(--clr-primary);
    }

    .opened ul {
      background-color: var(--bg-primary);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      width: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .opened .has-submenu ul {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .opened ul li {
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    .opened ul li.has-submenu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: min-content;
    }

    .has-submenu ul {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .opened ul li .active {
      border-block-end: unset;
    }

    .closed ul {
      display: none;
    }

    .nav-top.opened a {
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .header-container .btn-primary {
      display: none;
    }

    .btn-menu {
      background-color: var(--bg-tertiary);
      border: 0;
      font-size: inherit;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    .btn {
      border: none;
    }

    .btn-primary {
      background-color: var(--bg-tertiary);
      color: var(--clr-primary);
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 790px) {
      .nav-top .btn-menu {
        display: none;
      }

      .nav-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1rem;
      }

      .nav-list li.has-submenu {
        position: relative;
      }

      .nav-list li.has-submenu ul {
        display: none;
      }

      .closed ul,
      .opened ul {
        display: inherit;
      }

      .nav-list li.has-submenu:hover ul {
        background: var(--bg-primary);
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        top: 100%;
        width: fit-content;
        width: -moz-fit-content;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
      .header-container .btn-primary {
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-top {
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <header id="header" class="header hero">
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="header-container">
        <a href="../index.html" aria-label="Homepage" class="logo">
          <img src="/assets/logo.svg" width="248" height="54" alt="">
        </a>
        <nav class="nav-top closed" id="nav-top" aria-label="Main">
          <button type="button" id="btn-menu" class="btn btn-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu">
            Men&uuml;
            <span class="sr-only">&ouml;ffnen</span>
          </button>
          <ul id="nav-list" class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="../index.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="../services" aria-expanded="false">Services &darr;</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/planung">Planung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/instandhaltung">Instanthaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/montage+verlagerungen">Montage und Verlagerungen</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu">
              <a href="../produkte" aria-expanded="false">Produkte &darr;</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/hebeeinrichtung+hubtische">Hebeeinrichtungen / Hubtische</a></li>
                <li><a href="/haengefoerdersysteme">H&auml;ngef&ouml;rdersysteme</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ketten-undgurtfoerderer">Ketten- und Gurtf&ouml;rderer</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="../kontakt" class="btn btn-primary">Anfrage senden</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
`;

class Header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showMenu = false;

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  openMenu() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;

    const toggle = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#btn-menu');
    const navBar = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#nav-top');

    const show = () => {
      toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
      navBar.classList.remove('closed');
      navBar.classList.add('opened');
    };

    const hide = () => {
      toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      navBar.classList.remove('opened');
      navBar.classList.add('closed');
    };

    this.showMenu ? show() : hide();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#btn-menu').addEventListener('click', () => this.openMenu());
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#btn-menu').removeEventListener();
  }
};

window.customElements.define('header-component', Header);
```

Now I do have some function with add changes to this `header-compontent` depending on the window element itself (scroll) or window.size. But I do not have access to anything inside the header-component or using the window outside I do not have access to the elements withing the `header-compontent`.

How is header or footer typically handled within a large vanilla JS application? I thought custom components is the answer, but adding functionality seem difficult and barely answers on how to rewrite these function (which seem common to me) to use within a custom component.

#### Functions from index.js

close open menu in mobile view on scroll

```
const toggle = document.getElementById("btn-menu");
const navBar = document.getElementById("nav-top");
const menuItems = document.getElementById("nav-list").getElementsByTagName("a");
const menuItemsArray = [...menuItems];

window.addEventListener("onscroll", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (toggle.getAttribute("aria-expanded") == true) {
    hide();
  }
});

const handleClosure = (e) => !navBar.contains(e.target) && hide();
const handleResize = () => {
  if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
    navBar.classList.remove("opened");
    navBar.classList.add("closed");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("click", handleClosure);
window.addEventListener("focusin", handleClosure);
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
menuItemsArray.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", hide);
});
```

#### Or active menu items

```
const current = window.location.href;

for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  if (menuItems[i].href === current) {
    menuItems[i].className = "active";
    // menuItems[i].focus();
  }
}
```

and some others, I am sure I can figure out myself when I get these working.

Comment: ``const navBar = document.querySelector("header-component").shadowRoot.querySelector("#nav-top");``  Better yet, set (getter) properties on your ``<header-component>`` that return the ``#nav-top``

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I do face a problem when using querySelector, as well as getElementsByTagName for the header-component. When using console log, it does not show the tag but [object HTMLCollection] or [object HTMLElement]. Can you show me how and where to write the getter function?

Comment: JavaScript.info is a good site to learn: https://javascript.info/property-accessors
``getElementsByTagName`` is oldskool code; stick to ``querySelector`` and ``querySelectorAll`` If ``console.log`` doesn't log properly it seems you are using a REPL of CodePen? the **real** console logs the DOM elements correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman for sending me the link. I am using the console in inspect mode dev tools. I am working in VSCode. But sleeping over it seemed to work. I do now have it correctly in my console and can start implementing it as you suggested. Thanks.